# Android save overall score

Tags: android, int, save

I've made a little android game and I have a problem saving the overall score which should be retrieved every time the app starts up again instead of just starting at the default 0 like it always does.

I looked at SharedPreferences but that seems to be more about saving high scores that won't change.

Is there a way for my save the a score which will be changed as more games are played?

I assume I'd need to do the following:

- Retrieve the saved score
- Put it into a variable
- Change that variable
- Save it again end of game or every-time it changes (depending on whether or not it affects performance)

Edit:  Turns out SharedPreferences would work for this scenario.  Now could someone please provide an answer of how to implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can use Shared Preference for that purpose.
It can be used to save your score, overwrite the score and retrieve the score.
Shared preference uses the Key value pair.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd come to the conclusion that SharedPreferences would be more suitable for non-changing values.
I think this is an excellent use case for it.

You could try other persistence options (such as integrating SQLite into your app) but this seems like the quickest option with the least amout of overhead.

Still, if you're interested in other options, I hope you've skimmed through the storage options in the Android documentation:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

And, of course, using SharedPreferences will have to be done in conjunction with Application LifeCycle methods (such as onResume, onPause, etc):
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SQLite database to save the score value. 
To retrieve you current score in the database use this query.

```
SELECT score from ScoreTable where id = userId;
```

Assign the retrieve value to a variable.

At the end of the game // Update the score value

```
int finalScore = initialscore + newScore

UPDATE ScoreTable SET score = finalScore WHERE id = userId
```